# Allocating space of 1 char to an int pointer

Tags: c

I am learning C and am a bit confused about why I don't get any warnings/errors from GCC with the following snippet. I am allocating space of 1 char to a pointer to int, is it some changes done by GCC (like optimizing the allocated space for an int silently)?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int *int_ptr;

int main()
{
  int_ptr ip;
  ip = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
  *ip = 1000;
  printf("%d", *ip);
  free(ip);
  return 0;
}
```

**Update**

Having read the answers below, would it still be unsafe and risky if I did it the other way around, e.g. allocating space of an int to a pointer to char? The source of my confusion is the following answer in the [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Array_length#C), in the function `StringArray StringArray_new(size_t size)` the coder seems to exactly be doing this `this->elements = calloc(size, sizeof(int));` where `this->elements` is a `char** elements`.

Comment: You might read about "undefined behaviour". Your code writes to memory that does not belong to it. That's illegal. Anything can happen. It may even look as if it was working properly.

Comment: So is the `ip` getting an allocated space for an int or for a char?

Comment: As Gerhardh said, "undefined behavior". It might *appear* to work at first, and then break more visibly after an OS update, for example.

Comment: It gets space for at least a char. But your code is not safe.

Comment: You allocate space for 1 byte, but perhpas the underlying system only works in chunks of 16 bytes. C does not have a "guaranteed failure" system. It fails if you *break* something, but even then, not always. It depends on what you break.

Comment: @Student You allocated 1 byte of storage for it, so you're only allowed to write 1 byte.  If you write to more than that, as your code does, then you are corrupting memory and likely to experience unexpected results, segmentation faults, etc.  It's a severe bug.  With a language like C, it's up to you to avoid such mistakes.  The code will run much faster than with an interpreted language, but it won't detect mistakes like this for you.

Comment: @Student In terms of what the platform *guarantees*, only one char. More might be actually allocated "under the hood", but that's an implementation detail and could change in future updates.

Comment: @TomKarzes So would it still be non-risky if I only write -128 to 127 in `ip`? I know this is all bad things to do, I want to just understand how the compiler looks at it.

Comment: Yes it's still risky. Use pointers of correct type.

Comment: @Student Don't typedef pointers

Comment: Writing a 32-bit int writes 4 bytes, regardless of their value, this isn't a compiler thing, it's what the processor does.

Comment: And btw, two common ways of storing the 16-bit number 1 is `0000000000000001` and `0000000100000000`. Read about endianess.

Comment: @Gerhardh That's one of many possible representations. And you're also assuming 32 bit width. It may be more or less.

Comment: `-128` means `0xFFFFFF80` (for 32 bit systems using little endian representation) when you use a `int*`. Data type are always same size on a given system. They don't shrink for small values.

Comment: @klutt you are right. That was imprecise. Reworded it.

Comment: @Gerhardh Nice, but you forgot to mention that you're assuming two complement ;)

Comment: The answer in Rosetta Code has the same error.  On a 64-bit system it only allocates 4 bytes for an 8 byte pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of calloc is of the type `void*` which implicitly gets converted to an `int*` type. The C programming language and GCC simply trust the programmer to write sensible casts and thus do not produce any warnings. Your code is technically valid C, even though it produces an invalid memory write at runtime. So no, GCC does not implicitly allocate space for an integer.

If you would like to see warnings of this kind before running (or compilation), you may want to use, e.g., Clang Static Analyzer.

If you would like to see errors of this kind at runtime, run your program with Valgrind.

**Update**

Allocating space for 1 `int` (i.e. 4 bytes, generally) and then interpreting it as a `char` (1 `char` is 1 byte) will not result in any memory errors, as the space required for an `int` is larger than the space required for a `char`. In fact, you could use the result as an array of 4 `char`'s.
The `sizeof` operator returns the size of that type as a number of bytes. The `calloc` function then allocates that number of bytes, it is not aware of what type will be stored in the allocated segment.

While this does not produce any errors, it can indeed be considered a "risky and unsafe" programming practice. Exceptions exist for advanced applications where you´d want to reuse the same memory segment for storing values of a different type.

The code on Rosetta Code you linked to contains a bug in exactly that line. It should allocate memory for a `char*` instead of an `int`. These are generally not equal. On my machine, the size of an `int` is 4 bytes, while the size of a `char*` is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

C has very little type safety and `malloc` has none. It allocates exactly as many bytes as you tell it to allocate. It's not the compiler's duty to warn about it, it is the programmer's duty to get the parameters right.

The reason why it "seems to work" is *undefined behavior*.  `*ip = 1000;` might as well crash. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Also you should never hide pointers behind typedef. This is very bad practice and only serves to confuse the programmer and everyone reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler only cares that you pass the right number and types of arguments to `calloc` - it doesn’t check to see if those arguments make sense, since that’s a *runtime* issue.

Yes, you could probably add some special case logic to the compiler when both arguments are constant expressions and `sizeof` operations like in this case, but how would it handle a case where both arguments are runtime variables like `calloc( num, size );`?

This is one of those cases where C assumes you’re smart enough to know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler only check Syntax, not Semantic.
Your code's Syntax is OK. But Semantic not.